# How to make tikz macro work with two arguments in this MWE?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tabularx, datatool

I want to generate a table from a csv file using the very helpful tool `datatool` and insert a round photo of each person surrounded by a circle, the color of which should be taken from the provided csv file as well, see the MWE below:

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,DIV=6,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{datatool}


\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.05\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X} %for id
\newcolumntype{n}{>{\hsize=.1\hsize\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} %for name
\newcolumntype{y}{>{\hsize=.2\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X} %for everthing else
\newcolumntype{e}{>{\hsize=.3\hsize\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} %for email

\DTLloaddb[noheader]{data}{namelist.csv}

\newcommand{\circleme}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}
        \clip [rounded corners=.4cm] (0,0) rectangle coordinate (centerpoint) (.8,.8cm);
        \node [inner sep=0pt] at (centerpoint) {\includegraphics[width=.8cm, height=.8cm]{#1}};
      \end{scope}
      \draw[\mycolor,very thick] (.4cm,.4cm) circle (.4cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}}

  \begin{filecontents*}{namelist.csv}
    1,Name One,PhD,supervisor,Immunology,nameone@yahoo.com,logo,red
    2,Name Two,MSc,worker,Microbiology,nametwo@yahoo.com,logo,blue
    3,Name Three,BSc,worker,Chemistry,namethree@yahoo.com,logo,green
  \end{filecontents*}

  \newcommand{\tabcontents}{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}snyyyey@{}}
                            \toprule
                            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Name}}
                            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Qual}}
                            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Specs}}
                            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Descr}}
                            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{E-mail}}
                            &}

  \begin{document}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \DTLforeach*{data}{\idcode=Column1,\name=Column2,\qual=Column3,%
    \descr=Column4,\spec=Column5,\email=Column6,\figpath=Column7,\mycolor=Column8}%
  {%
    \eappto\tabcontents{\noexpand\\\noexpand\midrule                            
      \idcode \noexpand&
      \name \noexpand&
      \qual \noexpand&
      \spec \noexpand&
      \descr \noexpand&
      \email \noexpand&
      \noexpand\raisebox{-.5\baselineskip}{\noexpand\circleme{\figpath}}}
  }%
  \appto\tabcontents{\\\bottomrule\end{tabularx}}

\tabcontents%
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-engine: xetex
%%% End:
```

**Output**
[image]

The desired output is to have the first circle in red, the second in blue, and the third in green as dictated by the csv file. How to make tikz macro take this argument per the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another argument to `\circleme` and pass `\mycolor` to it:

> [image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,DIV=6,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.05\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X} %for id
\newcolumntype{n}{>{\hsize=.1\hsize\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} %for name
\newcolumntype{y}{>{\hsize=.2\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X} %for everthing else
\newcolumntype{e}{>{\hsize=.3\hsize\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} %for email
\usepackage{datatool}


\DTLloaddb[noheader]{data}{namelist.csv}

\newcommand{\circleme}[2]{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}
        \clip [rounded corners=.4cm] (0,0) rectangle coordinate (centerpoint) (.8,.8cm);
        \node [inner sep=0pt] at (centerpoint) {\includegraphics[width=.8cm, height=.8cm]{#1}};
      \end{scope}
      \draw[#2,very thick] (.4cm,.4cm) circle (.4cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}}

  \begin{filecontents*}{namelist.csv}
    1,Name One,PhD,supervisor,Immunology,nameone@yahoo.com,example-image-a,red
    2,Name Two,MSc,worker,Microbiology,nametwo@yahoo.com,example-image-b,blue
    3,Name Three,BSc,worker,Chemistry,namethree@yahoo.com,example-image-c,green
  \end{filecontents*}

  \newcommand{\tabcontents}{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}snyyyey@{}}
                            \toprule
                            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Name}}
                            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Qual}}
                            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Specs}}
                            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Descr}}
                            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{E-mail}}
                            &}

  \begin{document}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \DTLforeach*{data}{\idcode=Column1,\name=Column2,\qual=Column3,%
    \descr=Column4,\spec=Column5,\email=Column6,\figpath=Column7,\mycolor=Column8}%
  {%
    \eappto\tabcontents{\noexpand\\\noexpand\midrule                            
      \idcode \noexpand&
      \name \noexpand&
      \qual \noexpand&
      \spec \noexpand&
      \descr \noexpand&
      \email \noexpand&
      \noexpand\raisebox{-.5\baselineskip}{\noexpand\circleme{\figpath}{\mycolor}}}
  }%
  \appto\tabcontents{\\\bottomrule\end{tabularx}}

\tabcontents%
\end{document}
```

Comment: a new thing to learn, thanks.